# Laravel 5.1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php when trying to delete something from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am building an application where users can like/unlike each others projects. I have build a system that allow users to like the work and every like gets stored in my database with a unique id, the project_id and the user_id.

Now I am building the Unlike part and get an error when hitting the Unlike button.

The error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>   NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

My routes:

```
Route::post('projects/{id}', 'LikesController@store');
Route::get('projects/{id}','LikesController@destroy');
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $like = new Like;
    $like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $like->project_id = $input['project_id'];
    $like->save();
    return redirect('projects/'.$input['project_id']);
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    Like::find($id)->delete();
    return redirect('projects/'.$input['project_id']);
}
```

My form

```
@if (Auth::check())
                @if ($isLikedUser)
                    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/'.$project->id.'/deletelike','method'=>'POST')) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('project_id', $project->id) !!}
                    {!! Form::Submit('Unlike', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                @else
                    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/'.$project->id,'method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'likeform')) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('project_id', $project->id) !!}
                    {!! Form::Submit('Like', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                @endif
    @else
            <p>Log in to like.</p>
    @endif
```

Comment: Edited OP. Added correct error message.

Comment: write `php artisan route:list` on the command line and post your registered routes. Can you also write the stack trace?

Comment: I am aware that the projects/{id}/deletelike route does not exist, I don't have a view for it or anything I just wanna use it to delete a like. It could be projects/{id}/hellothere it doesn't matter much since I just wanna use to delete a like. Is this correct or not?

Comment: Both of your method is post, just change: `Route::post('projects/{id}','LikesController@destroy');`

Comment: I did this and now when I go to a project and press 'Like' the like with the project id gets deleted. For example: I go to project 6, this project has 0 likes. I press Like and like with id 6 gets deleted.

Comment: Use this: `Route::get('projects/delete/{id}','LikesController@destroy');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Route states that delete is done when the method id GET. But in your unlike button your form method is POST. Change that to GET. And also the action url you are giving for the delete is `'projects/'.$project->id.'/deletelike'` But in your routes you dont have a route structured like this. Also if you post this using GET, then hidden project_id is not required since it is already passed in the url. So your delete form should look like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/'.$project->id,'method'=>'GET')) !!}
{!! Form::Submit('Unlike', array('class'=>'send-btn')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Edit 1
Better change your Routes like this, and use post for both like and unlike:

```
Route::post('projects/like/{id}', 'LikesController@store');
Route::post('projects/unlike/{id}','LikesController@destroy');
```

and in your form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/like'.$project->id,'method'=>'POST')) !!}
```

and for unlike form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'projects/unlike/'.$project->id,'method'=>'POST')) !!}
```

and your delete method should be

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    Like::whereProjectId($id)->whereUserId(Auth::user()->id)->delete();
    return redirect('projects/'.$input['project_id']);
}
```

Comment: Will I be able to delete something from my database with the GET method?

Comment: And there need to be a difference between the like and unlike method I changed the like/unlike both to post and when I press the like button it goes to the unlike function in my controller

Comment: Use post for both like and unlike, but change the route as I have edited in the comment.

Comment: Ok I changed it and it works. Unfortunately the wrong like gets deleted. The like with the project id im in gets deleted. I believe this is caused by the $id in the destroy function. For example there is a like with id 6 and I press unlike in project 6 that like with id 6 gets deleted instead of the like from the logged in user who is watching that project

Comment: you are sending project_id as a parameter to destroy function, send the id of the specific like instead.

Comment: And how do I do this exactly? Shouldn't I do a querry to find the right like with something like this where id=Auth::id()?

Comment: yes send the project_id as it is, just change your delete method something like I have specified above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94584/discussion-between-moussa-chaabar-and-milan-maharjan).